# How do I get a VAR from jquery passed to a php query request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $article = null;

    $('#category').change(function() {
        var $categoryName = $('#category').val();

        if ($article == null) {
            $article = $('<h4>Select a business you wish to view.</h4><select id="business" name="business"   class="business"><option value="0">Select A Business To View Listing</option></select>').appendTo('.query');
        }
        $("#business").load("php.php");
    });
});
</script>
```

This is what I am currently doing, I am loading the php.php script, instead I want to pass the value of $categoryName to the WHERE clause in my query so it's like this:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect(,,,,);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
       echo "<option>Failed to connect to MySQLi</option>" ;
       }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Bname, Category FROM Business WHERE Category='$categoryName'");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['Bname']."'>".$row['Bname']."</option>";
      }
      // Free result set
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The way this should work is, the first select box is populated by php on my server showing a list of categories. A user selects a category from that box and onchange, a second select box is created, added to the form, and will query, to populate all of the business name's listed in my database that share a category(i.e the selectedindex from the first box) Can you help me change this to work how I need it to?

UPDATE: This is the updated code, now the second select box never loads.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var $article = null;

 $('#category').change(function () {
 var categoryName = $('#category').val();

 if ($article == null) {
 $article = $('<h4>Select a business you wish to view.</h4><select id="business" name="business" class="business"><option value="0">Select A Business To View Listing</option></select>').appendTo  ('.query');

  $("#business").load( "php.php",
     data:{myVar:$categoryName}
  );
  }
 });
 });
</script>
```

Heres the php.php

```
 <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect(,,,,);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
       echo "<option>Failed to connect to MySQLi</option>" ;
       }
    $myVar = $_GET["myVar"];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Bname, Category FROM Business WHERE Category='$myVar'");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['Bname']."'>".$row['Bname']."</option>";
      }
      // Free result set
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: Recommend you start with the `load` documentation of jQuery http://api.jquery.com/load/  There you can specify the `$categoryName` as part of the `data` object accepted by `load` and then you can `get` the variable in PHP

Comment: I'm very new to Jquery and php, can you show me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As seen below you can make a `data` object with one parameter `myVar`
JS:

```
$('#category').change(function() {
    var $categoryName = $('#category').val();

    if ($article == null) {
        $article = $('<h4>Select a business you wish to view.</h4><select id="business" name="business"   class="business"><option value="0">Select A Business To View Listing</option></select>').appendTo('.query');
    }
    $("#business").load("php.php",
         data:{myVar:$categoryName}
    );
});
```

Then get the variable in PHP like this
PHP:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(,,,,);
$myVar = $_GET["myVar"];
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "<option>Failed to connect to MySQLi</option>" ;
   }
```

Comment: I tried it like this, but now the second select box does not populate:

Comment: @learningPHPJquery You seem to have the wrong impression of how to interact with PHP.  You need to split the two out, when the select `change`s, you request via AJAX a page at `whatever.php` passing it the data as described.  Then the value returned or `echo`d out by that PHP script will be inserted into the element you called `load` on.

Comment: UPDATE: I added it as an answer by accident

Comment: Ok, I added it as an update, I followed what you said but now the second select box does not load, this can be seen on my server @ www.masswarveterans.com

Comment: Am I calling $myVar wrong in the where clause of the sql statement?

Comment: @learningPHPJquery no, technically it all looks correct.  Perhaps you can test with an industry where you know you should have listings?

Comment: I have tried them all, still wont load. I appreciate all the help! This is the biggest problem with godaddy hosting, 99% of things you do correct still don't work.

Comment: Perhaps you can try placing an `echo` statement in each of the conditionals as perhaps your getting errors which aren't set to `display` by your hosts php config.